# Mapbox LocationEngineResult.getLastLocation always return null

Tags: java, android, cordova, cordova-plugins, mapbox

I'm creating a cordova plugin that should return the device's position using `mapbox`. The issue is that `LocationEngineResult.getLastLocation()` is always returning `null`.

I use `locationEngine` to retrieve the location with `locationCallback`.

Permissions are also checked.

```
    ***
    LocationEngine locationEngine;
    AltGeolocationLocationCallback callback = new AltGeolocationLocationCallback(this);

   ***

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private void initLocationEngine() {
        locationEngine = LocationEngineProvider.getBestLocationEngine(this.cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext());

        LocationEngineRequest request = new LocationEngineRequest.Builder(DEFAULT_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS)
                .setPriority(LocationEngineRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                .setMaxWaitTime(DEFAULT_MAX_WAIT_TIME).build();
        locationEngine.requestLocationUpdates(request, callback, Looper.getMainLooper());
        locationEngine.getLastLocation(callback);
    }

    private static class AltGeolocationLocationCallback extends Activity
            implements LocationEngineCallback<LocationEngineResult> {

        private final WeakReference<AltGeolocation> activityWeakReference;
        private AltGeolocationLocationCallback contexto = this;

        AltGeolocationLocationCallback(AltGeolocation activity) {
            this.activityWeakReference = new WeakReference<>(activity);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LocationEngineResult result) {
            AltGeolocation activity = activityWeakReference.get();
            if (activity != null) {
                Location location = result.getLastLocation();
                  Log.d(LOG_TAG, "result: " + location );

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
            AltGeolocation activity = activityWeakReference.get();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPointerCaptureChanged(boolean hasCapture) {

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: try to run it on a real device instead of emulator

Comment: @UsamaAltaf I am running it on real device